# Distribution formed by functions of elements of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If you have a multivariate normal (MVN) distribution of format

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
   b \\
   c
 \end{pmatrix} \sim MVN \left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   \sigma^2_a & \sigma_{a,b} & \sigma_{a,c} \\
   \sigma_{a,b} & \sigma^2_{b} & \sigma_{b,c} \\
   \sigma_{a,c} & \sigma_{b,c} & \sigma^2_{c}
 \end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$

And you wish to find the multivariate normal distribution formed by taking functions of the elements of the original distribution - (in my case, I want to find distributions similar to):

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
   c-b 
 \end{pmatrix} \sim MVN \left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 
 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   \sigma^2_a & \sigma_{a,c-b} \\
   \sigma_{a,c-b} & \sigma^2_{c-b} 
 \end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$

Some elements appear straightforward:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_a &= \sigma_a \\
\sigma_{c-b}&= \sqrt{\sigma^2_{b}+\sigma^2_{c}-2\sigma_{b,c}}
\end{aligned}
$$

However, could anyone give an example / point me to a paper or textbook that explains how to find the covariance between an element of a multivariate normal distribution, and a function of elements in the same multivariate normal distribution? So how you go about calculating the covariance between $a$ and $c-b$, which I'm denoting $\sigma_{a,c-b}$.  I can find many examples for uncorrelated distributions, but I'm struggling to find a clear example where you have functions of correlated elements.  Any pointers / advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT** - Answered:

Based on the link provided by d.k.o., the solution is to use affine transformations:

$$
X= \begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
   b \\
   c
 \end{pmatrix} \sim MVN \left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   \sigma^2_a & \sigma_{a,b} & \sigma_{a,c} \\
   \sigma_{a,b} & \sigma^2_{b} & \sigma_{b,c} \\
   \sigma_{a,c} & \sigma_{b,c} & \sigma^2_{c}
 \end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$

Let $Y=c+BX$.  Set:

$$\begin{aligned}
c&=\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
 \end{pmatrix}\\
B&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}\\
B^T&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $Y$ has distribution $Y\sim MVN \left( c+B\mu , B\Sigma B^T \right)$ with $B\Sigma B^T$ equal to:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   \sigma^2_a & \sigma_{a,c}-\sigma_{a,b} \\
   \sigma_{a,c}-\sigma_{a,b} & \sigma_c^2+\sigma_b^2-2\sigma_{b,c}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

Comment: thank you - very helpful link. For information I'm adding my own working based on the affine transformation section (see edit above)